# Suspending Windows Store App: Error when calling MvxSuspensionManager.SaveAsync()

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, mvvmcross

I have a WinRT app using MvvmCross where I want to store the current session state.

In the OnLaunch method of tha App.xaml.cs I register the content frame of my app with the suspension manager:

```
...
var setup = new Setup(_contentFrame);
setup.Initialize();

var suspensionManager = Mvx.GetSingleton<IMvxSuspensionManager>() as MvxSuspensionManager;
suspensionManager.RegisterFrame(_contentFrame, "FrameNav");
...
```

Whenever I suspend the app and run the code in the OnSuspending event handler

```
var suspensionManager = Mvx.GetSingleton<IMvxSuspensionManager>() as MvxSuspensionManager;

await suspensionManager.SaveAsync();
```

I get the following exception.

```
Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsStore.Views.Suspension.MvxSuspensionManagerException "MvxSuspensionManager failed"
at Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsStore.Views.Suspension.MvxSuspensionManager.<SaveAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
at ****App.xaml.cs:line 129
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException "Unbekannter Fehler
"
at Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame.GetNavigationState()
at Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsStore.Views.Suspension.MvxSuspensionManager.SaveFrameNavigationState(Frame frame)
at Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsStore.Views.Suspension.MvxSuspensionManager.<SaveAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
```

I am pretty sure I can narrow the exception root to the WinRT API call to

```
Frame.GetNavigationState();
```

that is executed by the MvxSuspensionManager. When I call this function directly it will fail with the same error.

I know the WinRT frame navigation stack can only be serialized if non complex types are used as navigation parameters. But my app crashes even if I just suspend on the first page.

Maybe my approach of suspending with MvvmCross is wrong or I missed some steps to be setup correctly.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems that are disabling the suspension manager. As you said, MvX does navigation with complex (ViewModelRequests) objects and not strings. You fix this by creating your own ViewPresenter, which should look like this:

```
public class CustomViewPresenter : MvxStoreViewPresenter {
    //XXX: Holding a ref here because base class's ref to the frame is for some reason private.
    private Frame _curFrame;
    public CustomViewPresenter(Frame RootFrame) : base(RootFrame) {
        _curFrame = RootFrame;
    }

    public override void Show(MvxViewModelRequest request) {
        try {
            var requestTranslator = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxViewsContainer>();
            var viewType = requestTranslator.GetViewType(request.ViewModelType);

            var converter = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxNavigationSerializer>();
            var requestText = converter.Serializer.SerializeObject(request);

            _curFrame.Navigate(viewType, requestText);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            MvxTrace.Trace("Error seen during navigation request to {0} - error {1}", request.ViewModelType.Name,
                           exception.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

In your base page object, the one that inherits from MvxStorePage, this to deserialize the stringified VMRequest. DO NOT call the base onnavigatedto method:

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e) {
        var reqData = (string)e.Parameter;

        var converter = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxNavigationSerializer>();
        var req = converter.Serializer.DeserializeObject<MvxViewModelRequest>(reqData);

        this.OnViewCreate(req, () => LoadStateBundle(e));
    }
```

Once you've done all this, you have another problem. Mvx serializes bundles as Dictionary*string, string*, while the suspension manager that's bundled with Mvx can only deal with Dictionary*string, object*. You'll have to copy and paste the standard suspension manager that Microsoft ships into your app, and change this:

```
private readonly List<Type> _knownTypes = new List<Type>();
```

To this:

```
private readonly List<Type> _knownTypes = new List<Type>() { typeof(Dictionary<string, string>) };
```

Then, you'll need to feed your altered SuspensionManager to MvX by adding the following lines to your setup.cs file:

```
    protected override Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsStore.Views.Suspension.IMvxSuspensionManager CreateSuspensionManager() {
        return new MyFixedSuspensionManager();
    }
```

Hopefully this should all be rolled into one of the future releases of Mvx so we don't have to do all these backflips.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. It was driving me insane that my CustomPresenter didn't really have any use as I was missing: this.OnViewCreate(req, () => LoadStateBundle(e)); in all of my views.

Comment: This solution has now been merged into MvvmCross

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess this isn't an error in your use - but is instead an error somewhere in the MvvmCross adaption of the 'standard' `SuspensionManager` - probably in the object type being saved.

The `SuspensionManager` code within MvvmCross was largely based on the Windows8.0 `Common` template for `SuspensionManager` - but I recall there were a lot of frustrations during early development (using the various preview releases) with `COMException`s which frequently returned such unhelpful messages as `unknown error`.

In practice, Windows 8 suspension hasn't (so far) risen very high in the priority list for MvvmCross users - so I wouldn't be surprised if there were additions or fixes needed to this current adaption (especially as Windows moves into 8.1 where LayoutAwarePage has been deprecated). The load/restore state from within MvvmCross is used in many apps for 'in-memory' cache state, but I've personally not used it for resuming an app from 'suspend and shutdown' termination state.

If your app **needs** this working suspension functionality with saving to/from disk, then I believe the `MvxSuspensionManager` and associated `MvxStorePage.SaveStateBundle` and `MvxStorePage.LoadStateBundle` code can be made to work with a little debugging, and I believe that the important methods are all marked `virtual` so that they can be easily overridden, but... sadly... I believe getting them working may be a frustrating debugging experience including moment of 'unknown error' from `COMException`